# Replace some of string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, replace, sql-server-2008-r2

I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Since it's not that easy to perform regex in SQL Server, I'll need some advice in how to solve this problem.

I have a column with the following type of data:

```
id   Ville
------------------
1    Saint azeraze
2    Saint ooiqsdf
3    Saint fefeee
```

I want to replace `Saint` into `St`, in order to get this result:

```
id   Ville
---------------
1    St azeraze
2    St ooiqsdf
3    St fefeee
```

How can I do this with `replace` ?

```
UPDATE TheTable
SET Ville = REPLACE(Ville, '????', '????')
WHERE Ville LIKE 'Saint%'
```

Comment: i think it is fine,  do you get any error on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE TheTable
SET Ville = REPLACE(Ville, 'Saint ', 'St ')
WHERE Ville LIKE 'Saint %'
```